# Why is my picture box null even if it shows an image?

Tags: c#, winforms, image, nullreferenceexception, picturebox

I have a picture box with an image like

```
   PictureBox picBox = new PictureBox();
   Image img = Image.FromFile(imagePath);
   picBox.Image = img;
   picBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
   ...
   ...
   picBox.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(picBox_MouseEnter);
   ...
```

And when I try the event handler like this:

```
void picBox_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox pic = sender as PictureBox;

        if (pic != null) // or pic.Image !=null
        {
            this.Text = pic.ImageLocation;
        }
        else
        {
            this.Text = "NULL";
        }
    }
```

It's always null. Isn't there any way to solve it? Please help me to make the picture box and image in the picturebox not null.

Comment: Perhaps you forgot `this.Controls.Add(picBox)`?

Answer (score 1):

When you set the `Image` property manually `ImageLocation` property will be `null`. Instead you can set `ImageLocation` property and ask picture box to get do the rest of the job for you.

```
picBox.ImageLocation = imagePath;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use load(), it will solve the problem:

```
picBox.Load(imagePath)
```